# Showing only raw code

Tags: doxygen

I've got a tree view which redirects the user to each of the files contained in my project.
I would like to disable the "link to source code" and directly show the source code without having to click twice. 
Which Doxygen option do I check?
Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at editing the layout file to include only the files?

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout

At the top of the layout xml there is the index. Set visibility to "no" for all the parts you don't want to include.